# Is Alastor Moody's wand his staff?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, wandlore

Mad-Eye had a staff which he used to cast a spell on a Death Eater in HP5.

[image]

Is this staff his wand (or does he not have a wand) and if that was his 'wand', how did it function?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81359/what-does-a-wizard-do-if-he-loses-his-wand/81360#81360

Comment: [Moody had a wand](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Alastor_Moody%27s_wand) - https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/d/d3/AlastorMadEyeMoodywandNN8288.jpg

Comment: @Valorum [Indeed](https://www.amazon.com/Funko-Harry-Potter-Mad-Eye-Figure/dp/B01LEJD98A)

Comment: @Valorum You mean his eye?  Because is Moody's eye his wand?

Comment: "*which he used to cast a spell on a Death Eater in HP5*" can you provide a quote?

Comment: @ibid - It's only in the film. During the fight in the Department of Mysteries, he taps it against the ground and a spell is fired out at a Death Eater.

Comment: @ThruGog - The movies are weird.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Mad-Eye Moody had a wand, but his staff could have served as a backup wand.**

Mad-Eye Moody had a regular wand as well as the staff.

[image]

[image]

He only uses the staff to cast a spell once (in the movie). Other than that, he uses a wand, and his staff is never said to have magical capability in the books. For the most part, his staff is basically just an ordinary walking stick,even if it has the ability to be used to cast spells.

It's possible that his staff may have had some kind of ability to function as a backup wand, in case he was ever disarmed in a duel, because Moody believes in constantly being prepared and ready for any situation. Ollivander has confirmed that magic can be channeled through almost anything, although well-matched wands are the most effective choice.

> "If you are any wizard at all you will be able to channel your magic through almost any instrument. The best results, however, must always come where there is the strongest affinity between wizard and wand. These connections are complex. An initial attraction, and then a
>   mutual quest for experience, the wand learning from the wizard, the
>   wizard from the wand." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 (The Wandmaker)*</sup></sub>

It seems to be made of wood, like most wands are, so it could conceivably function as a very oversized wand, especially if it was made from a wood with magical properties like most common wand woods. It probably wouldn't be as good as a small wand, which would be much easier to wield, but it could work somewhat.

[image]

Comment: Mad Eye's original movie wand looked like this:  https://www.yourprops.com/movieprops/original/yp501baa045a8812.76157807/Harry-Potter-movies-Mad-Eye-Moody-s-Wand-with-Ollivanders-Box-1.jpg

Comment: But then strangely the Noble Collection started making this larger one. Not sure if he ever used a different wand as you don't really see it after Goblet of Fire https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mad+eye+wand&client=ms-android-h3g-gb&source=android-browser&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzkPz11ZHTAhUKJcAKHZhHB_8Q_AUIBygB&biw=360&bih=512#imgrc=91jnMsWTROKQGM:

Comment: Perhaps add Ollivander's quote about channeling magic through anything?

Comment: I've added a pic with his movie wand

Comment: I've added a picture of Mad-Eye Moody holding his wand. Also, I added in what Ollivander said about being able to channel magic through almost anything.. Thanks, everyone, for your suggestions!

Comment: Of *course* Moody has a back-up for his wand.  Stuff's always going pear-shaped when you're an Auror, especially when you're an Auror and Fudge is the Minister of Magic.

Comment: While it is movie not book, Lucius carried his wand around in his walking stick, and IIRC, Hagrid smuggled a wand in his umbrella.

Comment: @JohnP Yes, you’re correct on both counts! :)

Comment: Even more importantly, it has a knob on the end :)